# I/flutter ( 4135): RPCError: got code -32000 with msg "invalid sender"

Tags: dart, flutter

getting error while doing ethereum transaction in flutter

> I/flutter ( 4135): RPCError: got code -32000 with msg "invalid sender".
>   E/flutter ( 4135): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RPCError: got code -32000 with msg "invalid sender".

```
Transaction(keys: credentials, maximumGas: _maximumGas)
          .prepareForSimpleTransaction(
              new EthereumAddress(
                  _to),
              EtherAmount.fromUnitAndValue(
                  EtherUnit.ether, 1))
          .send(Client());
```

Comment: Have you got the solution to this issue ? Please help.